# Proof of equality on the limit of the Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

## Question

$(X, m, \mu)$ be the measure space.
Let $f: X \to [0, \infty]$ be a measurable function and assume that
$$
\int_X f\ d\mu < \infty.
$$
For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $A$ and $f_n$ be as follows.
$$
A(n) = \{x \in X \mid f(x) \leq n \}, f_n = f \chi_{A(n)}
$$
Show that the following holds.
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_X |f-f_n|d\mu = 0
$$

## What I know

From the definition of $f_n$, $f_n<f_{n+1}$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Using the monotonic convergence theorem$(*)$, we have
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_X |f-f_n|d\mu &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_X |f|(1-\chi_{A(n)})d\mu\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\int_X |f|d\mu - \int_X |f\chi_{A(n)}| d\mu \right) \\
&=\int_X |f|d\mu - \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_X |f_n|d\mu \\
&=\int_X |f|d\mu - \int_X \left( \lim_{n\to\infty} |f_n| \right) d\mu\ (\because *)\\
&=\int_X |f|d\mu - \int_X |f|d\mu = 0.
\end{align}

Is it correct?

Comment: You can justify the interchange of limit and inetgral using either the Monotone Convegence Theorem or DCT.

Comment: @geetha290krm I knew it. I would appreciate it if you could check the formula deformation as it is described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monotone convergence is not needed here. Since $f$ is nonnegative and by assumption has finite integral, for any $\varepsilon>0$ we may choose a positive integer $N$ such that $\mu(X\setminus A(N))<\frac\varepsilon N$. Then for $n\geqslant N$ we have
$$
\int_X |f-f_n|\ \mathsf d\mu = \int_{A(N)}|f-f_n|\ \mathsf d\mu + \int_{X\setminus A(N)}|f-f_n|\ \mathsf d\mu< 0 + N\cdot\frac\varepsilon N = \varepsilon,
$$
so that the limit is zero.

Comment: I understand what you are writing, but on the other hand, is the solution I wrote incorrect?